# Most efficient way to get the maximum X and Y from a dictionary of lists of X-Y tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a dictionary of lists of (x, y) pairs, what is the most efficient way in Python 3 to find the maximum x and the maximum y in the dictionary even if those values are in different (x, y) pairs?

```
roi =   {  '26580.BOT': [(107, 1006),
                         (107, 973)],
           '26580.TOP': [(107, 1008),
                         (107, 1040),
                         (107, 1072),
                         (107, 1648)],
           '26582.TOP': [(113, 977)],
           '26685.TOP': [(105, 974)]}
```

Comment: I don't see a better solution than the trivial one that involves traversing all the values of the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally use a for-loop over the `values`, because it will do a single pass over the data and it is space efficient, but if you prefer hard-to-read one-liners, there's always `reduce` :)

```
>>> import functools, itertools
>>> def max_tuple(t1, t2): return max(t1[0],t2[0]), max(t1[1],t2[1])
...
>>> ts = itertools.chain.from_iterable(roi.values())
>>> functools.reduce(max_tuple, ts)
(113, 1648)
```

Note, this is space efficient! If you are worried about speed, use the loop, or, you can try this alternative implementation for the reducing function:

```
>>> def max_tuple2(t1, t2):
...     (a,b), (x,y) = t1, t2
...     return (a if a > x else x, b if b > y else y)
...
```

Which has tested significantly faster for me, let's make a bigger test-dict:

```
>>> roi2 = {k+str(i): v*100 for k, v in roi.items() for i in range(100)}
```

And now, some tests:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('ts = itertools.chain.from_iterable(roi2.values()); functools.reduce(max_tuple, ts)', 'from __main__ import functools, itertools, max_tuple, roi2;', number=100)
4.612322789034806
>>> timeit.timeit('ts = itertools.chain.from_iterable(roi2.values()); functools.reduce(max_tuple2, ts)', 'from __main__ import functools, itertools, max_tuple2, roi2;', number=100)
1.7526514289784245
```

So well over twice as fast using `max_tuple2`. But if speed is your concern, use the naive-forloop approach. Here is @AdiC 's solution, prettified a bit:

```
>>> def max_from_values(d):
...     m1 = m2 = float('-inf')
...     for tlist in d.values():
...         for a, b in tlist:
...             if a > m1:
...                 m1 = a
...             if b > m2:
...                 m2 = b
...     return m1, m2
...
>>> max_from_values(roi2)
(113, 1648)
```

And look, it is *well over three times faster than the fastest previous*, and almost *ten times faster than the original*:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('max_from_values(roi2)', 'from __main__ import max_from_values, roi2;', number=100)
0.4867470810422674
```

Comment: That's very surprising that the naive for-loop approach is faster. I wonder why that is?

Comment: @empty it's not *surprising at all*. Most of the iterator constructs, like generator expressions, zip-ing, etc, have a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 4):

Basic idea: get a list of all x-values and all y-values, then get the max of each of those individual lists.

```
import itertools
x,y = zip(*itertools.chain(*roi.values()))
print(max(x),max(y))
```

Explanation: `roi.values()` gets all the values from the key-value pairs, then `itertools.chain(*...)` combines the lists of 2-tuples into 1 list, then finally `zip(*...)` inverts the lists so that instead of a list of `k` of 2-tuples, you have 2 k-tuples, which you can get the `max` of.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
x = 0
y = 0

for key in roi:

    foo = roi[key]

    for item in foo:

        if item[0] > x:
            x = item[0]

        if item[1] > y:
            y = item[1]
```

This program loops through each key of the dictionary. It loops through each tuple and compares the 'x' and 'y' values.

I'm assuming that the first element in each tuple is the 'x' and the second element is the 'y'.

Comment: This approach is the most straightforward and it is what I would probably use in real code, but just a suggestion, use `for value in roi.values()` and them `for a, b in value:`

Answer (score 2):

```
list(map(max, zip(*[(x, y) for pair in roi.values() for x, y in pair])))
# [113, 1648]
```